# solr how to get most nearest match of title

Tags: solr

For example I want to search "adidas Bright Pink Sleeve Free Shirt"
the result set should be in the following order
the top result should be the product having above name with exact match.
then products with partial match of the query 
then products with any of the match.

the solr schema has following fields
product_name, 
brand, 
category.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if your field type is TextField and your analyzer chain for that type includes [LowerCase filter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory) (to match adidas to Adidas). I would also enable [autoGeneratePhraseQueries](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml).